# Why is this code removing `False` from the array?

Tags: python, codewarrior

This is the task:

> Write an algorithm that takes an array and moves all of the zeros to the end, preserving the order of the other elements

What is wrong with this code? Why is it not keeping boolean values while iterating through the list and removing zeros? Is it because `False` is equal to `0`?

```
move_zeros([False,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1])

def move_zeros(array):
    count=0
    for num in array:
        if num == 0:
            count +=1
            array.remove(0)
            
    return array +[0]*count
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `False == 0` will evaluate to `True` in Python which is why `False` values are being removed from your array.

In Python, `True` and `False` are [implemented as singletons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/#specification), meaning all `False` values point to the same instance. Therefore, you can use the `is` operator to check if a value is *exactly* equal to this singleton.

`False is 0` will return `False`, while `False == 0` will return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = len(lis)
y = []
for i in range(len(lis)):
    if lis[i]!=0:
        y.append(lis[i])
if len(y)!=len(lis):
    z = len(lis)-len(y)
    for i in range(z):
        y.append(0)
```

Seems like its a homework problem. Happy to help tho.

Edit: use print(y) and you'll get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed `False == 0`. Actually, `bool` is a subtype of `int`. If you want to strictly compare if `False` is equal to `0`, then another comparison should be added to the `if` statement.

Also, do not modify a list while you are iterating over itself. Create a new one instead.

```
def move_zeros(list_):
    result = []
    zeros = 0
    for item in list_:
        if item == 0 and type(item) == int:
            zeros += 1
            continue
        result.append(item)
    return result + [0] * zeros
```

Comment: why remove is not working??? can you give a solution using remove attribute

Comment: `remove()` is a method, not an attribute. If you change the list while it is being iterated (like using `remove()`), then the order of the elements is going to be changing and the `for` loop will behave unpredictably. That's why it's never a good idea to edit a list while you're iterating over itself.

Comment: Also, when you call `remove(0)`, that method will not discriminate between `0` and `False` therefore it will remove `False` from the list

Answer (score 0):

Yes 0 evaluates to False and 1 evaluates to True, use this

```
def move_zeros(obj):
    new_list = []
    zeros_list = []
    for item in obj:
        if item != 0 or is False:
            new_list.append(item)
        else:
            zeros_list.append(item)
    new_list.extend(zero_list)
    return new_list
```

This adds all non 0 to one list and all 0's to another, then returns the new_list after iterating over the zeros_list and adding them to the end of the new_list

Comment: Please note that this will return `None`, as the call to `extend()` returns that.

Comment: And try to avoid using `list` as a name, since it is already used by the `list` class of the `__builtins__` module.

Comment: I apologize for the oversight and have edited the code to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1. You *directly changed* the list *over which you iterate* — it is always *dangerous*.
2. Other answers explained to you why `False == 0` is `True`.

I made as few changes in your code as it was possible to fix these issues:

1. I created a new, empty array, and instead of removing “bad” elements from the original list, I appended the “good” ones to that new array.
2. I tested a current element for its type, too.

---

```
def move_zeros(array):
    count=0
    new_array = []
    for num in array:
        if num == 0 and type(num) is int:
            count +=1
        else:
            new_array.append(num)

    return new_array + [0]*count
```

---

*Test:*

```
move_zeros([False,1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1])
```

> ```
> [False, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> ```